# Why is the file path for stream_context_set_option screwy?

Tags: php, ssl

I have some PHP scripts in the following directory structure.

```
ROOT  
---COMMON  
------(Login.php)  
---APPSERVICE  
------(NotificationService.php)  
------NOTIFICATION_CERTIFICATES  
---------(ck.pem)
```

In `NotificationService.php`, I have the following line in my `"notifyUser()"` function:

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', **'NOTIFICATION_CERTIFICATES/ck.pem'**);
```

However, when I include NotificationService.php in my Login.php script and try to call notifyUser(), it gives me this error:

```
stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure in [my file path]
```

However, if I call `notifyUser()` from a script in the same directory as `NotificationService.php`, there is no error. Why does the bolded line above seem to be affected by the script calling the function, rather than the location of the script that the function is defined in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relative paths are resolved based on the [`include_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) setting; this typically includes the current working directory that's established at the start of each request.

If you want to make sure the path is always taken relative to the current script that's being run:

```
// NotificationService.php

$cert = __DIR__ . '/NOTIFICATION_CERTIFICATES/ck.pem';
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $cert);
```

Comment: The answer is ok now, however, the question is definitely a duplicate of a duplicate of duplicates. Anyhow, the answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks for actually helping instead of just whining about duplicate questions like the guy above me. Not everyone is familiar enough with the language to figure out how to ask the question properly, much less find someone else's.